# Probability of A or B happening, where B can only happen when A does not happen

Tags: probability

I am trying to determine the probability of a certain scenario, but I'm confused.

Event $A$ can happen with $0.35$ likelihood. If $A$ **does not** happen, $B$ can happen with $0.50$ probability.

What are the odds of either A or B happening?

What's confusing me, is that $B$ is dependent on $A$ and I don't know how to correctly factor that into the probability.

Comment: I would recommend reading http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes'_theorem :)

Answer (score 2):

Note that:
$$
\Pr(A)=0.35\\
\Pr(A^c)=1-0.35=0.65\\
\Pr(B|A^c)=0.5
$$
AND therefore:
$$
\Pr(A\cup B)=\Pr(A)+\Pr(B\cap A^c)=\Pr(A)+\Pr(B| A^c)\Pr(A^c)=0.35+0.65\times 0.5=0.675
$$